# Building a file index in Linux

Tags: linux, indexing, awk, grep, find

I have a filesystem with deeply nested directories. Inside the bottom level directory for any node in the tree is a directory whose name is the `guid` of a record in a database. This folder contains the binary file(s) (pdf, jpg, etc) that are attached to that record.

Two Example paths:

```
/g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs0/FOO/042014/27/123.456.789/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
/g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs1/FOO/052014/22/321.654.987/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
```

In the above example, `123.456.789` and `321.654.987` are `guid`s

I want to build an index of the complete filesystem so that I can create a lookup table in my database to easily map the `guid` of the record to the absolute path(s) of its attached file(s).

I can easily generate a straight list of files with:

```
find /g/camm/MOUNT -type f > /g/camm/MOUNT/files.index
```

but I want to parse the output of each file path into a CSV file which looks like:

```
GUID    ABSOLUTEPATH    FILENAME
123.456.789 /g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs0/FOO/042014/27/123.456.789/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf    04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
321.654.987 /g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs1/FOO/052014/22/321.654.987/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf    04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
```

I think I need to pipe the output of my find command into `xargs` and again into `awk` to process each line of the output into the desired format for the CSV output... but I can't make it work...

Comment: `extremely slow` means?  if find is for you too slow, you may think about writing a program to traverse the FS tree  in multi-threads..

Comment: I've edited the question to remove questions about performance... really I'm just looking for a command that can parse the output of the `find` into the desired CSV format at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for your long-running `find` to finish, then you
can pass the list of filenames through awk:

```
awk -F/ '{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$(NF-1),$0,$NF}' /g/camm/MOUNT/files.index
```

and this will convert lines like

```
/g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs0/FOO/042014/27/123.456.789/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
```

into

```
123.456.789,/g/camm/MOUNT/raid_fs0/FOO/042014/27/123.456.789/04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf,04.20.30--27.04.2014--RJ123.pdf
```

The `-F/` splits the line into fields using "/" as separator, `NF` is the
number of fields, so `$NF` means the last field, and `$(NF-1)` the
next-to-last, which seems to be the directory you want in the first column
of the output. I used "," in the printf to separate the output columns, as
is typical in a csv; you can replace it by any character such as space or ";".

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there can be anything much faster than your `find` command, but
you may be interested by the **locate** package. It uses the `updatedb` command, usually run each night by cron, to traverse the filesystem and creates a file holding all the filenames in a manner than can be easily searched by another command.

The `locate` command is used to read the database to find matching directories, files, and so on, even using glob wild-card or regex pattern matching.  Once tried, it is hard to live without it.

For example, on my system `locate -S` lists the statistics:

```
Database /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db:
    59945 directories
    505330 files
    30401572 bytes in file names
    12809265 bytes used to store database
```

and I can do

```
locate rc-dib0700-nec.ko
locate -r rc-.*-nec.ko
locate '*/media/*rc-*-nec.ko*'
```

to find files like `/usr/lib/modules/4.1.6-100.fc21.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media/rc/keymaps/rc-dib0700-nec.ko.xz` in no time at all.

Comment: Thanks for this general solution. Not sure it's useful in my use case... i'm actually running this on a windows server (through msysgit) to make an index of a filesystem that's on a network drive in a data warehouse. It has to happen twice ever as it's on a static data extract that we have now and will be updated one more time and then become permanently static. If I can build this CSV index in the desired format then I can import it into SQL server and put a WebService on top of it to map user download requests to the correct UNC path in the enterprise...

Answer (score 0):

You can nearly do what you want with the `find`'s `-printf` option.
The difficuty is on GUID.

Assuming prefixes have the same length as in your example, I would probably do:

```
find /g/camm/MOUNT -type f -printf "%h %p %f\n" | colrm 1 37 > /g/camm/MOUNT/files.index
```

Or if the number of `/` is constant

```
find /g/camm/MOUNT -type f -printf "%h %p %f\n" | cut -d '/' -f 9- > /g/camm/MOUNT/files.index
```

Otherwise, I would use `sed`:

```
find /g/camm/MOUNT -type f -printf "%h %p %f\n" | sed -e 's@^.*/\(.*\) @\1 @' > /g/camm/MOUNT/files.index
```